# Parameter field in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

How to use the parameter field to get values from dataset in [Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports)?

How can I assign a SQL query to the parameter field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the article

[Tip: How to pass Crystal Report Parameters Programmatically?](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/paramInCR11012006132839PM/paramInCR.aspx)